# Compton's formula for change in wavelength

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering

I want to measure the shift in wavelength predicted by Compton's formula. I find that I cant measure a shift of less than 5% and that I also cannot measure at angles greater than 150 degrees. What is the longest X-ray wavelength that I can use and still observe the shift:

Note that Compton's formula is:

$$ \Delta \lambda =\frac{hc}{mc^2}(1-cos\theta) $$

How can I solve this problem?

This is my thinking: We are interested in a percentage, but $\Delta \lambda$ is the difference between the final and initial wavelengths, not the percentage. Am I suppose to assume an incident wavelength?

$$  \frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda} =\frac{hc}{\lambda mc^2}(1-cos\theta) $$

$$  0.05 =\frac{hc}{\lambda mc^2}(1-cos(150)) $$

$$  \lambda =\frac{hc}{0.05 mc^2}(1-cos(150)) $$

$$\lambda = 90.5625 pm$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should start by assuming the wavelength used, $\lambda$, as known. The information you have is just sufficient to extract $\lambda$ in terms of the relative shift $\eta = \Delta \lambda / \lambda$ and the scattering angle $\theta$. All you have to do is maximize $\lambda$ in terms of $\eta$, $\theta$.

Comment: @urdv I am not exactly what you mean, could you expand this? I dont know what $\lambda$ is. What value do I assume for it?

Comment: @JacksonHart Oh, you don't have to know $\lambda$ before hand, you calculate it! Rewrite $\eta = \Delta \lambda / \lambda$ by substituting the equation you have for $\Delta \lambda$. Treat the result as an equation that you can solve for $\lambda$. What you get is an expression for $\lambda$ as a function of $\eta$ and $\theta$. Look carefully at this expression. When is it maximized as $\eta$, $\theta$ vary? That's the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @urdv Did you get a chance to look at my approach in the question?

Comment: @urdv Are you not looking at my edited question at all? I have edited it. I do not have $\pi$ in there anymore. *Please* look at my edited question where I attempt the method you pointed out.

Comment: @JacksonHart Sorry, didn't look. Yep, you got it. Will delete my last 2 comments.